# ¿Como obtener valores de una misma tabla?

Tags: sql

Buen día.
Me surge la duda de como puedo realizar lo siguiente:
Cuento con una tabla en la cual tengo como campos principales Id y SuId.
En esta misma tabla cuento con el campo Factor, que contiene valor y en algunos caso un código.
Lo que intento realizar es poder identificar los Factores que coincidan con Id y SubId.
Por ejemplo tengo lo siguiente en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la primera linea esta el Id = 61 y SubId = 6 con Factor 1.
Y en la segunda linea esta el Id = 526 y SubId = 1005 con Factor {"x":{"i":61,"s":6}}},
donde aquí tenemos {"i":61,"s":6}, que esto quiere decir que el Id = 526 y SubId = 1005
esta relacionado con Id = 61 y SubId = 6.
Intento armar un query que me ayude a identificar este tipo de datos.
He probado con INNER JOIN, pero no es el resultado esperado.
De antemano gracias.


EDITADO


La idea es la siguiente:
La base tiene la tabla Decatec, con los valores Id, SubId y Factor.
En algunos Id, campo Factor viene un código, y con ese código se puede ver una relación con otros Id, por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es realizar un query que me busque aquellos Id y SubId que en el factor tengan una relación, el resultado seria asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente esa es la idea.

Comment: Con un formato customizado como este (que no es XML o JSON), y estando toda la información en un string en una sola columna, cualquier alternativa va a ser extremadamente lenta (además de técnicamente compleja)

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender lo que quieres decir con "identificar este tipo de datos", quizás ayude ver qué es lo que has intentado y una explicación de por qué no te ha funcionado, ya que si "identificar" es relacionar las líneas, parece bastante alcanzable. Al [edit] la pregunta no olvides incluir la etiqueta del motor de base de datos que utilizas.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo del resultado que esperas

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el motor de base de datos que utilizas es SQL Server.

Factor '{"x":{"i":61,"s":6}}}' tenía una llave de cierre (}) de mas para ser un json válido, que yo le saqué, no se si si estaba a propósito o es un error de tipeo.

Mi query:

Primero obtengo el Id y el SubId de la columna Factor (si la cadena en Factor es un json válido) subquery sqFactor, luego hago un LEFT JOIN entre la tabla original (la he nombrado: t) y la subquery sqFactor (de esta manera te va a mostrar las filas vinculadas y las que no tienen vinculación).

```
SELECT t.*, sqFactor.Id, sqFactor.SubId
FROM t
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT 
                 t.Id,
                 t.SubId,
                 JSON_VALUE(Factor, '$.x."i"') AS FId,
                 JSON_VALUE(Factor, '$.x."s"') AS FSubId
           FROM t
           WHERE ISJSON(Factor) = 1) AS sqFactor ON t.Id = sqFactor.FId AND t.SubId = sqFactor.FSubId
ORDER BY t.Id, t.SubId;
```

Salida (con tus datos de ejemplo):

| Id | SubId | Factor | Id | SubId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61 | 6 | 1 | 526 | 1005 |
| 526 | 1005 | {"x":{"i":61,"s":6}} | null | null |

EDITADA según las nuevas especificaciones:

```
SELECT sqFactor.Id, sqFactor.SubId, sqFactor.Factor, d.*
FROM  (
           SELECT 
                 Id,
                 SubId,
                 Factor,
                 JSON_VALUE(SUBSTRING(Factor, 1, LEN(Factor) - 1), '$.x."i"') AS FId,
                 JSON_VALUE(SUBSTRING(Factor, 1, LEN(Factor) - 1), '$.x."s"') AS FSubId
           FROM Decatec
           WHERE ISJSON(SUBSTRING(Factor, 1, LEN(Factor) - 1)) = 1) AS sqFactor 
           
INNER JOIN Decatec d ON d.Id = sqFactor.FId AND d.SubId = sqFactor.FSubId
ORDER BY d.Id, d.SubId;
```